# Accessing fields in a drop down element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate some tasks at work with Selenium so this is my first time using it.

I am up to a portion of my code where I need to select several values from a 'drop-down' menu.

I access this menu by doing this:

```
metrics_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='metrics']")
metrics_element.click()
```

Then for a sanity check I want to see all my options in this menu so I do this, as per the documentation:

```
all_options = metrics_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
for option in all_options:
    print option.get_attribute('value')
```

This returns me what I thought were dictionaries:

```
{"id": "1", "name": "name_1", "field": "field_1", "service": "service_1" }
{"id": "2", "name": "name_2", "field": "field_2", "service": "service_1" }
{"id": "3", "name": "name_3", "field": "field_3", "service": "service_1" }
```

When I tried accessing them as dictionaries I was greeted with an error. How would I go about selecting certain fields. For example say I wanted to select where it was `name in ('name_1', 'name_3')`? And moreso in general how would I go about selecting metrics from this `metrics_element`? Thanks!

**Edit**: Here is the `HTML` of this menu

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_metrics" style="width: 400px;">
    <ul class="select2-choices">  
        <li class="select2-search-field">    
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"    autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input select2-default" id="s2id_autogen5" style="width: 398px;">  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly you tried to access those values?

Comment: I tried loading them into a `simplejson` dict however, it takes too long as there are a lot of possible fields. What would be the best way to access them?

Comment: I could just manually enter all those values ahead of time. Then copy their `xpath` from the source code and then create a loop to select all of them. There has to be a more efficient way than that, right?

Comment: It would be better if you add `HTML` source for mentioned drop-down as it's not quite clear what you want to do

Comment: I posted an edit with the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `name` value for each option and to select required option you can use below code:

```
import re

all_options = metrics_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
for option in all_options:
    print re.search('(?:(name_\d))',option.get_attribute('value')).group(0)  # to get all values
all_options[0].click() # to select first option
```

**Update**

If you need to send some values to input field, use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen5']").send_keys('some_value')
```

Let me know if this is not what you want

Comment: This gives an error, string indices must be integers

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy, real `HTML` is little different than on example :) Your values really looks like a `JSON`? Do you need to send text into those `input` fields or just get the value?

Comment: I need to send text into those input fields, that is where my trouble is. @Andersson